# How can I convert rows into columns conditionally in mysql? Read body please

Tags: php, mysql, datatables

I have a table that has data as such

```
id | customerName  | Campaign questionId | answerID | caseID | 
1  |   john        | Inbound | 1         | 2        | 1
2  |   john        | Inbound | 2         | 3        | 1 
3  |   john        | Inbound | 3         | 1        | 1
4  |   john        | Inbound | 4         | 5        | 1
5  |   john        | Inbound | 5         | 4        | 1
6  |   john        | Outbound| 6         | 7        | 1
7  |   john        | Outbound| 7         | 9        | 1
8  |   john        | Outbound| 8         | 2        | 1   
9  |   john        | Outbound| 9         | 1        | 1
10 |   john        | Outbound|10         | 4        | 1
```

Details: A customer can have multiple cases and each case can have two surveys for each customer as outbound and inbound. There are in total 10 pre-defined questions to be used for these surveys. 5 for outbound and 5 for inbound. In my current situation, I am able to get data as shown above,  1 row for each question and answer. In Total= for a customer that has 1 case and 2 campaigns thats 10 rows. 
My objective is to get 2 rows per customer, per case. 1 row for inbound and other for outbound. Rather than having a row for each question with repetetive information, I am looking for columns for each question. 
Desired Outcome:

```
id|Name|caseId  |Campaign | Q1 | Q2 | Q3 | Q4 | Q5
1 |John|  1     |Outbound | 2  | 3  |1   | 5  | 4
2 |John|  1     |Inbound  | 7  | 9  |2   | 1  | 4
```

Total questions: 10 predefined questions;
Outbound survey: 5 questions
Inbound Survey: 5 questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get your desired results using conditional aggregation to perform a pivot, and grouping over `caseID`, `customerName` and `Campaign`:

```
SELECT customerName,
       caseID,
       Campaign,
       MAX(CASE WHEN questionID % 5 = 1 THEN answerID END) AS Q1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN questionID % 5 = 2 THEN answerID END) AS Q2,
       MAX(CASE WHEN questionID % 5 = 3 THEN answerID END) AS Q3,
       MAX(CASE WHEN questionID % 5 = 4 THEN answerID END) AS Q4,
       MAX(CASE WHEN questionID % 5 = 0 THEN answerID END) AS Q5
FROM data
GROUP BY caseID, customerName, Campaign
```

Output:

```
customerName    caseID  Campaign    Q1  Q2  Q3  Q4  Q5
john            1       Inbound     2   3   1   5   4
john            1       Outbound    7   9   2   1   4
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wdSwHfWKHgWkphJanQevmj/0)

Comment: Thank you Nick. I have gone through the fiddle and it is exactly what I was looking for. However, one small question, If the two surveys were to share a mutual question. lets say qId 4 being in both. In this case, the answer becomes null.

Comment: @MuhammedSabi That seems odd. Can you modify my fiddle to demonstrate the problem?

Comment: Sorry my bad. It works fine. Turned out there was a problem with my dataset.